# How to create an android screen lock method

Tags: android, credential-providers

in windows, we can add credential provider to do what u wants

Can we do it in android?
What i'm trying to accomplish is to build a custom credential provider that i can unlock the mobile using face recognition

thnx

Comment: Isnt face recognition already built-in?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html

Comment: yes it is already built and included in some androids, but i need to build one by my own... not just for face recognition, but i can do other ways...